# WCF Application Service with Passive STS using WSFAM

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, wif

There are lots of examples which show a ASP.NET web application that is secured with Passive STS. 
I'm trying to apply a working ASP.NET example on simple WCF Application Service, using WSFAM, SAM, VS2012/.Net4.5.
Once I open up the browser on localhost/Service1.svc the browser is redirected to the STS, posts the token back to the service (RP) and then gets redirected again to the STS, the loop goes endlessly.

I plan on implementing ASMX endpoints eventually, which is why I have to use WCF.

Does it make sense that a WCF will use Passive STS for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WCF you should have a look at the WSFederationBinding.  The passive scenario makes little sense for WCF service.  A Passive scenario will always show a user interface on the STS.  You should normally obtain a token in the part of your app that has a user interface ( a website or a windows app) and then pass the token to the WCF service.

Comment: What would be the right approach if I want to implement both Active and Passive STS Auth with WCF? My initial thought would be to use ASP.net to authenticate with Passive STS and then delegate all requests to the WCF Service backend using the token..

Comment: The passive approach for WCF has no sense. Passive means it stops for user credentials. Active means that it obtains the token somehow (for example from the sts) and goes to the service carrying the token.